# Entity Data Model Wizard, Code first from existing database, not generating code

Tags: ef-code-first

I am using the Entity Data Model Wizard and selecting "Code First from database" to create my model.

For some tables this works as expected.

However for my ExportCustomer table no code gets generated and no error is available

The table structure is given by

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExportCustomer](
    [CoLastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CardID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CardStatus] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CurrencyCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1AddressLine1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1AddressLine2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1AddressLine3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1AddressLine4] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1City] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1State] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Postcode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Country] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Phone1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Phone2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Phone3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Fax] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1email] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Website] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1contactname] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Address1Salutation] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ABN] [varchar](355) NULL,
    [PaymentIsDue] [int] NULL,
    [DiscountDays] [int] NULL,
    [BalanceDueDays] [int] NULL,
    [CreditLimit] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

When I make CardID the primary key the code generation works.
I suspect that a primary key is required.